# Red5 1.0 does not play any videos after seeking

Tags: red5, seek

I'm using Red5 1.0.0-RC2 and it doesn't play any video after seeking a previous one. The process is the following:
1. start the Red5 server
2. open the client in the browser and "play" with the seekbar
3. shortly it stops working
4. reload the browser
5. it does not play anything and in the red5 console output there are no lines such as:

> [INFO] [pool-4-thread-1] videocv.Application - W3C x-category:stream x-event:play c-ip: x-sname:f0fd1a01-6c68-4bf5-b0e6-18d55921baa0
>
> [INFO] [pool-4-thread-1] videocv.Application - streamPlayItemPlay
>
> [INFO] [pool-4-thread-1] videocv.Application - W3C x-category:stream x-event:play c-ip: x-sname:f0fd1a01-6c68-4bf5-b0e6-18d55921baa0 x-name:1/2/1.flv

Comment: Upgrade to 1.0.2, seeking has been fixed for quite awhile in the newer versions now.

Answer (score 0):

Can you duplicate that issue on demo.openmeetings.de ? We are basically using Red5 too, I don't think that issue is a general issue, it more has todo with your specific app or the video that you playback.

Sebastian